# Can't see how to disable an AlertDialog Box

Tags: java, android, alert

I'm trying to figure out how to disable definitely an AlertDialog Box when I press the negative/positive button. My current app works tapping the screen and I want my app to show an AlertDialog Box at the first tap. This Box says "attention, some of the names are invented!" and the buttons are "Ok!"(positive button) and "Don't remind this to me"(Negative Button). In both cases I want the app to stop showing the Box at each tap because it's obviously frustrating and it has no sense to show a message at each tap (consider the user is going to tap 1 or 2 times every 5 secs). So I'm trying to figure out how to disable it after the first tap.

For now, this is what I wrote

```
   public void tap(View view) {

    final AlertDialog.Builder tapAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    tapAlert.setMessage("The names are mostly invented!");
    tapAlert.setPositiveButton("Ok!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
    tapAlert.setNegativeButton("Don't remind it to me", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


            dialog.cancel();

        }

    });
    tapAlert.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            // do nothing, just allow dialog to close
            // this happens on back button getting hit
        }
    });
    tapAlert.setTitle("Attention!");
    tapAlert.create();
    tapAlert.show();
```

Comment: java != javascript ftfy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a `boolean variable at class level

```
boolean firstTap = true;
```

Then change that after it has shown once

```
public void tap(View view) {

    final AlertDialog.Builder tapAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    ...
    if (firstTap) {
        tapAlert.show();
        firstTap = false;
    }
```

This will work if you want it to show the first time every time the app runs. If you only **ever** want it to show on the first tap the save the boolean in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) and check that when the Activity starts.

**Even better** would be to check that variable before calling the `tap()` method. Don't call it when `firstTap` is `false`.

Comment: Just tried and it's working smoothly, thanks ;) Just a question: what if I want to make the AlertDialog visible at each time the app starts when the user presses "Ok!" and never more visible if the user presses "Don't remind it to me!"? Should I use SharedPreferences?

Comment: Yes, SharedPreferences. Just save a boolean if it is false, don't show it

Comment: Sorry if I'm such inexpert, can you give me a sample of code? I mean, I'm trying to see how to save it through SharedPreferences but I'm having a few issues on finding the right guide :)

Comment: The link in my answer gives a good example and there are tons on SO and other places on the internet to get you started with that. and [here is an example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html) of a more in-depth settings activity